# div should fill available space - display table scrambles my layout

Tags: html, css

I have already done a lot of research and I have found out that I should use `display: table;` and `display: table-row;` to solve my problem but this approach totally scrambles my layout.

At the moment it looks like that:

http://jsfiddle.net/f07dkm8u/

and like in the jsfiddle described I would like to expand my div to fill the height.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your desired layout can be produced using flexbox. Give the container `display: flex` and align it horizontally using `flex-direction: column`.

The child item needs to be set `flex: 1` which expands and shrinks with the remaining height.

Check for the browser support: [**Can I use**](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox)

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#top {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
  display: flex; /* Add Flexbox model */
  flex-direction: column; /* Horizontal alignment */
}
#head {
  background-color: red;
}
#content {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: orange;
  flex: 1; /* Expand with the parent element */
}
#bottom {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="top">
  <div id="head">
    I don't know this height;
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>End :)
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    <div id="a">
      All my Text! :)
    </div>
    <div id="b">
      SomeStuff!
    </div>
    This div should fill up thill my buttom div
  </div>
</div>
<div id="bottom">
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome :) Just check out for the browser support: http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox